# Blazor WASM Page Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

Is there a way to define the page route of a razor component through a variable? One of the reason why I want it to be done this way is that whenever I need to define a redirect link on another page, I can just use the variable rather than hard coding it again.

By default, when we want to define a razor component as a page we do it like

```
@page "/product/{id}"
```

I want it to be centralized in a sense, that it would look something like this

```
public class PageRoute
{
    public const string ProductInfo = "/product/{id}";
}
```

and then I will be calling it on the razor component as

```
@page PageRoute.ProductInfo
```

Comment: You can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0),The 'page' directive expects a string surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to be centralized in a sense, that it would look something like this
> ....

No, not with out of the box Blazor.  `@page = "/"` gets pre-compiled into an attribute :

```cs
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]
public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase {
....
}
```

Which is fixed at compile time.  If you want a dynamic router you'll need to write your own router.  Search the Interent for "Blazor Dynamic Routing" and "Blazor Custom Routing" for more information.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for, the attribute has helped me do what I want. Cheers!